# Wrong centered merge in Davinci Resolve's Fusion

Tags: davinci-resolve, fusion

I have created a standard "button" composition

[image: Fusion Composition]

But when I click in the Merge9 node, it only moves the text keeping the retangular background static.

[image: Moving]

I was expecting that the ending merge to move it entirely and with its center correctly aligned with the retangular object.

I'm using Davinci Resolve 17

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move the two things together, use a transform node after they’ve been merged.